# Unable to connect to remote Geode cluster from Java

Tags: java, gemfire, geode

I use the below code to connect to remote Geode cluster

```
ClientCache clientCache =
        new ClientCacheFactory().addPoolLocator("www.abc.com", 10334).create();

Region<String, Customer> region = clientCache.getRegion("customers");
System.out.println("region => " + region);
```

Note: **www.abc.com:10334** is accessible from my machine.

Logs show Region connected to LocalRegion.

What should I do to connect to remote Geode cluster region ? I don't want to use Spring data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you're creating a `PROXY` or `PROXY_CACHE` region. Use something like this:

```
clientCache
  .createClientRegionFactory(ClientRegionShortcut.PROXY)
  .create("customers");
```

Comment: Thanks. I used PROXY & get exception **org.apache.geode.cache.RegionExistsException: /customers**. And the region is already created in server using gfsh. Is it possible to get the region ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with the help of below code

```
 ClientCache clientCache =
          new ClientCacheFactory().set("cache-xml-file", "cache.xml").create();
 customerRegion = clientCache.getRegion("customers")
```